# Redirect with properties of a bean as parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have my Controller like bellow who expect a `ModelAttribute` in type `Foo`  :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search") 
public String search(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Foo foo,
          HttpServletRequest request) {

        .....
}
```

In another controller i want to redirect my bean `Foo` as parameter of my request `/search`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/load_search") 
public String load_search(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Foo foo, 
            HttpServletRequest request) {

    Foo foo = myService.getFoo();
    return "redirect:/search";
}
```

So how can I achieve that? How to redirect to `/search` with my bean foo as parameter like this : `/search?arg0=..&arg1=..` where `arg0, arg1 , ...` are properties of bean `Foo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RedirectAttributes`. It is the special parameter, that allows you to pass data throw redirect. Lets consider example of your snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/load_search") 
public String load_search(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute Foo foo, 
            HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

    Foo foo = myService.getFoo();
    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("foo", foo);
    return "redirect:/search";
}
```

In target method `foo` will be added to the model automatically by Spring. If you need to map `foo` to the `@ModelAttribute` parameter, you should explicitly specify name of attribute like in the following example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search") 
public String search(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo,
          HttpServletRequest request) {

     //here 'foo' will be added to 'model' and mapped to 'foo'
     .....
}
```

More details about `RedirectAttributes` you can find out in Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-flash-attributes).

Comment: thanks man it works now .. i wish that the args appears in the request but it's okey.